# Creating a subquery within the From clause in order to refer to a archived table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a simple count(*) query to check the total number of entries in a table that gets archived everyday. However, I need this query to function everyday within my reporting functions so it should be useful everyday.

Unfortunately, when I run the query it simply treats it either as an error or a subquery with no data inside it.  Here's my troubleshooting query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
SELECT CONCAT('archivedtable__', REPLACE(SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), 1), '- 
',''));

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT CONCAT('archivedtable__', REPLACE(SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), 1), '- 
',''))) subquery;
```

The first gives an error, the 2nd will just return archivedtable__20190813 which is the correct name but doesn't actually get it to refer to the table.

Comment: You need to look into using `dynamic sql`... Several examples on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may think of using **[Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)**. For your hint here is an example:

**Pre-Requisite:** Create two tables with the dates of last 2 days i.e yesterday and day before yesterday.

```
SET @prefix := 'archivedtable__';

SET @date1 := REPLACE(SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), 1), '-','');
SET @table1 := concat(@prefix, @date1);

SET @date2 := REPLACE(SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), 2), '-','');
SET @table2 := concat(@prefix, @date2);

set @qry:= concat('SELECT COUNT(*) as t1,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ', @table1, ') as t2 FROM ', @table2);
prepare stmt from @qry;
execute stmt;
```

Comment: Is there anyway to be able to individually query this? It works, but I need to narrow it to 2 columns including the count(*) and then cross compare that to the current table.

Comment: Thanks man, A version of this was able to work. Marking correct

Answer (score 0):

You can build the SQL as a VARCHAR (or NVARCHAR) and then use sp_executesql.
Like this:

```
DECLARE @tblCount INT
DECLARE @tblName AS NVARCHAR(100) = CONCAT(.....)
DECLARE @countSql AS NARCHAR(200) = N'SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @tblName
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500) = N'@cnt INT OUTPUT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @countSql, @ParmDefinition, @cnt = @tblCount OUTPUT;

SELECT @tblCount;
```